# How to represent time without date in PHP

Tags: php

I'd like to represent time (standalone) in PHP without the date part.
I've tried using `strtotime` and `DateTime::createFromFormat` but both add a date part to it. Laravel's [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) library descends from `DateTime` and also doesn't cater for this.

My use case is that of representing bus depart and arriving times from a station. The buses depart everyday at the same time so I don't want/need the date part of it.

Python has `datetime.time` and Java has `java.time.LocalTime`, is there a direct equivalent of this in PHP? Should I create a custom class for it?

Cheers

Comment: `date('H:i:s');` - Just set what format you want the date/time to be presented in. You can define exactly what you want to show from a timestamp: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. `date()`, `DateTime` and `Carbon` all let you define this. Here's the manual for `DateTime::format()`: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php as well.

Comment: "_and also doesn't cater for this_" Looking at the [Carbon format page](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) you can see that Carbon has a method `toTimeString();`

Comment: @kerbholz - The OP has done zero research. This is a "straight-to-stackoverflow" type of question. There are _so_ many guides/tutorials about using date/time in PHP that it's almost impossible to not find the answer if you spend more than 5 minutes researching.

Comment: you're all trying to format the date to display the time part only. `date('H:i:s')` will return a string. `DateTime::format()` again is just formatting of a date time. Carbon's `toTimeString()` string also does the same. I want an object which I can do calculations on and be able to compare. If using a DateTime if I create a date today and tomorrow when I compare they'll be different. I think the simplest solution is to have a simple Time value-object.

Comment: @Magnus Could you point one out, then? Note that, as Paulo's comment says, a DateTime object or any of the date/time functions in PHP represent a unique point in time, _with a specific date_, rather than representing an abstract X o’clock value, and so none of them fits the requirement here. Using DateTime objects for comparison of o’clock values cannot be guaranteed to work, for example. So far, it seems Paulo’s own answer is the correct one: it’s simply not possible in PHP without creating your own class. If you can disprove that, please go ahead.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - The question doesn't include any example of what the OP is trying to do that `date('H:i:s')` wouldn't solve. The example about buses departure and arrival time isn't even close to a good description. Is the time for pure output? Does there need to be calculations? If the basic datetime functions doesn't cut it, there needs to be a proper example of why it wouldn't work. The OP also got an answer from Krzystof which the OP didn't even comment on. For those reasons, this question is a low quality question.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that's because as stated in his comment after yours that returns a string on which he can't do calculations

Comment: @Fuseteam - Please read my last comment again. The reason this is a low quality question is because the OP didn't include any examples of either the input data, expected output or what kind of calculations they need to do. If they, for example want to calculate in seconds, they can add a mock date like: `strtotime('1970-01-01 ' . $theTimeString)`. That would return a unix timestamp (integer). Would that do? Who knows.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it would not as the op has stated they are looking for a way to do time calculations that doesn't take date into account in addition to stating strtotime doesn't do what they want. In a sense date is extra 'bloat' in their usecase. They compare it to time objects in python and java; something, as they stated in their own answer after further research, that php doesn't have. this would imply they are/were looking for time objects equivalents in php

Comment: @Fuseteam Since you seem to know more about what the OP _really_ wants than anyone else (since the OP haven't given us a proper example),why don't you just write a real answer instead of commenting?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson because the OP already has found an answer, as for why i'm commenting? uhh wanted to see if i can get an answer from you based on what i believe the op meant, who knows maybe we'd be able to find an alternative answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP doesn't have a direct equivalent to either Python `datetime.time` nor Java  `java.time.LocalTime`. A `Time` value-object should be created for this case in a per-need basis.

Answer (score 5):

1. Create `DateTime` object and format this object to show only time:

   ```
   $date = new \DateTime("now");
   echo $date->format("H:i:s");
   ```

   or do the same thing in one line:

   ```
   echo (new \DateTime("now"))->format("H:i:s");
   ```
2. Use `date` function:

   ```
   echo date("H:i:s");
   ```

Comment: Beware of the server timezone though: some times may not exist and be automatically “fixed”: https://3v4l.org/9eEoN

Answer (score 2):

Even though PHP does not have a time-specific object type, standard `DateTime` (or `DateTimeImmutable`) works just fine for this purpose:

```
$time = new \DateTime('14:00');
echo $time->format('H:i');
// 14:00
```